# Dump a Sqlite memory database to disk with Marshal

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, serialization, sqlite

I would like to dump a Sqlite memory database to disk with Marshal but get the error below, here the complete test. The Sqlite API for saving in memory databases seems to be only usable in C.

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => "sqlite3",
:database  => ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :tests do |table|
    table.column :word, :string
  end
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base;end
Test.create(word: 'test')

puts Test.all.length
c = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection
File.open('sqlite_db.marshal','wb') { |f| f.write(Marshal.dump(c)) }
# => error `dump': can't dump hash with default proc (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sqlite3's [Backup](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/SQLite3/Backup) class.

```
# populate ActiveRecord here...

sdb = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

ddb = SQLite3::Database.new('backup.sqlite3')

b = SQLite3::Backup.new(ddb, 'main', sdb, 'main')
b.step(-1)
b.finish
```

Comment: that works for regular sqlite, thanks, but i would like to dump the activerecord database from my example

Comment: Doesn't `::ActiveRecord::Base.connection` retrieve the underlying sqlite3 database connection?

Comment: then i get the error i have in my question, I can't accept your answer because it's not using Marshal, for the moment i use a solution i'll publish here as an answer but that i can't accpet either because of the same reasen

Comment: What I meant was: can't you use the `c` from the code in your question as the `sdb` in my answer? Or is `c` not a sqlite3 database connection? I realize that your question asks to use Marshal, but that seems like a bad idea to me. SQLite and Marshal are both tools designed to save/load data on disk. Mixing them should be unnecessary and is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @peter I found the problem. You need to use `raw_connection` to get the sqlite3 connection. Then my answer works. I have edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment i use the following method, it is't a correct answer on my question so I'll leave it open, perhaps someone does find a solution using Marshal
Here I open a second connection to a disk database and load and write to that connection before and after.

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "sqlite3",
    :database => ":memory:"
  )
end

class Test2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "sqlite3",
    :database => "testing.db"
  )
  self.table_name    = :tests
end

def db_load
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    @connection = Test.connection
    create_table :tests do |table|
      table.column :word, :string
    end
  end
  Test2.all.each do |m|
    Test.create m.attributes
  end
end

def db_write
  Test2.delete_all
  Test.all.each do |m|
    Test2.create m.attributes
  end
end

def db_test klasse
  klasse.all.each do |record|
    p record
  end
end

db_load
db_test Test
Test.create(word: 'test3')
db_write
db_test Test2
```

gives

```
-- create_table(:tests)
   -> 0.0060s
#<Test id: 1, word: "test">
#<Test id: 2, word: "test2">
#<Test2 id: 1, word: "test">
#<Test2 id: 2, word: "test2">
#<Test2 id: 3, word: "test3">
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: that would be disordered wouldn't it, besides it is was a possible answer if nothing better showed up, so i disagree

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of the technique Max proposed.
It's not using Marshal and not for Activerecord but ussefull, so here for reference

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => ":memory:")

sdb = SQLite3::Database.new(':memory:')

sdb.execute "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cars(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Price INT)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)"
sdb.execute "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)"


ddb = SQLite3::Database.new('backup.sqlite3')

b = SQLite3::Backup.new(ddb, 'main', sdb, 'main')
b.step(-1)
b.finish

stm = ddb.prepare "SELECT * FROM Cars LIMIT 5" 
rs = stm.execute 

rs.each do |row|
  puts row.join "\s"
end
```

gives

```
1 Audi 52642
2 Mercedes 57127
3 Skoda 9000
4 Volvo 29000
5 Bentley 350000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for reference and completeness the final solution based on Max edited answer

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :database  => ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :tests do |table|
    table.column :word, :string
    table.column :index, :string
  end
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base;end
Test.create(word: 'test', index: 0)
Test.create(word: 'test2', index: 1)

sdb = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
ddb = SQLite3::Database.new('backup_sqlite3.db')

backup = SQLite3::Backup.new(ddb, 'main', sdb, 'main')
backup.step(-1)
backup.finish

ddb.execute("select * from tests").each do |record|
  p record
end
```